# Parsing JSON data from servlet in JavaScript

Tags: json, servlets

I am trying to parse json data returned from my servlet in JavaScript with JQuery, 
Here is JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//alert('document ready');
$('#search-btn').click(function(){
//  alert($('#searchbar').val());
    var url= 'http://localhost:8080/SMDE/Search?q='+$('#searchbar').val();
    //alert(url);
    var table='';
    $.get(url,function(response){
        //alert(response);
        if(response){
            //alert(response);
            $('#container').html(response);
            for(i=0;i<response.data.length;i++){
                var n= response.data[i].name;
                var c= reponse.data[i].category;
                var ii=response.data[i].id;
                table=table+"<div class='content'>" +
                        "<h3>Page Name :" +n+"<br/>"
                        "Category :" +c+"<br/>"
                        "</h3>" +
                        "<form action='/Profile' method='POST'>" +
                        "<input type='hidden' name='id' value='" +ii+
                        "'<input type='submit' class='btn' value='More...' /></form></div>";
            }
            $('#container').html(table);
        }
        if (response.error) {
              alert('Error - ' + response.error.message);
              //return
        } 
    });
}); });
```

When i uncomment alert(response); i get correct response, but if i alert(response.data) it says undefined. 
The result when url is directly given in browser is:

```
{ "data": [
{
  "category": "Media\/news\/publishing",
  "name": "CNN",
  "id": "5550296508"
},
{
  "category": "Media\/news\/publishing",
  "name": "CNN International",
  "id": "18793419640"
},
{
  "category": "Tv show",
  "name": "CNN Heroes",
  "id": "86418982488"
},
{
  "category": "Tv network",
  "name": "CNN en Espa\u00f1ol",
  "id": "89613772643"
},
{
  "category": "Media\/news\/publishing",
  "name": "CNNMoney",
  "id": "6651543066"
},
{
  "category": "News\/media website",
  "name": "CNNM\u00e9xico",
  "id": "323626813995"
}] }
```

Please help with processing data.

The servlet code is:

```
    import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.json.*;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class Search
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@WebServlet("/Search")
public class Search extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public Search() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String key = request.getParameter("q");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String result = Facebook.callGet("search?q="+key+"&type=page");
        try{
            /*JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
            response.setContentType("application/json");
            out.print(json);*/
            out.println(result);
        }catch(Exception e){
            out.println("error");
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the response content type in order to hint jQuery how to interpret the response body. In case of JSON, you need to set the response content type to `application/json`:

```
response.setContentType("application/json");
```

This way you don't need to hack around with ugly and security/error-prone workarounds like `eval()` as suggested in the other answer.

#### See also:

- [How to use Servlets and Ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112686/how-to-use-servlets-and-ajax)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a problem with the `$.get()` method. The method works asynchronously, hence the data received is undefined when you read it.
The alert statement adds delay to the whole process. That is why you are getting the data when the statement is uncommented.

- Use `$.post`
- Set the property `async:false` (makes it synchronous)
- Or put the UI rendering logic in the call back success function

Answer (score -1):

`$.get` reads in the raw response data. `response` is a plain string, no json at this point.

```
 $.get(url,function(response){
        var d = eval("("+response+")");
        alert(d.data);
```

Additionaly there is no closing `]` in your data.

Comment: Data has closing ] but this is trimmed one... in original data, the array has many elements..

Comment: Try `eval("("+response+")")`

Comment: Bad advice. Never use `eval()`. The `$.get()` just transparently recognizes JSON as long as content type is set right. OP apparently forgot to set the right content type.